# Shell script isn't working

Tags: shell

I can't find out what's happening. Is this regular expression not working for shell scripts?

```
sudo rm -R -f '/web/!(release)'
```

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you forgot to enable `extglob`. Also you shouldn't quote your extended glob pattern:

```
shopt -s extglob
sudo rm -R -f '/web/'!(release)
```

Also if the shell you're calling `sudo` with is not able to access `/web`, you can wrap up your command with `bash`:

```
sudo bash -c "shopt -s extglob"$'\n'"rm -R -f '/web/'!(release)"
```

See [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) and [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion).

Comment: Now it says .. 'bash: shopt: Doesn't exists'

Comment: Run it as `bash script.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

## Script file

```
shopt -s extglob

sudo rm -R -f 'web/'!(release);
```

## Result

script.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

edit :

I was running with "sh" instead of bash

now with bash script.sh it works

thanks